# Get all Nfts of a collection owned by a wallet using alchemy sdk

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, javascript, alchemy

I am using alchemy sdk , can u please tell me how I can use getNftsForOwner() to get all the nfts owned by a wallet of a particular contract adddress? I need the exact syntax. Thank u

Comment: Isn't the exact syntax available in their [docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnfts)? What are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

getNftsForOwner() accepts two parameters: owner and options (optional). Try passing any extra params as an object for options

Getting only nfts of a certain contract for an owner would look something like:

```
alchemy.nft
        .getNftsForOwner("0x9E29A34dFd3Cb99798E8D88515FEe01f2e4cD5a8", {
            contractAddresses: ["0x0c2e57efddba8c768147d1fdf9176a0a6ebd5d83"],
        })
        .then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

alchemy sdk changed something and so if you need, you can add pageKey to your sdk parameter.

```
...
alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwner("0xshah.eth", {pageKey: '88434286-7eaa-472d-8739-32a0497c2a18'}).then(console.log);
```

I refer this link: https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnfts

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Setup: npm install alchemy-sdk
// Github: https://github.com/alchemyplatform/alchemy-sdk-js
import { Network, Alchemy } from "alchemy-sdk";

// Optional Config object, but defaults to demo api-key and eth-mainnet.
const settings = {
  apiKey: demo, // Replace with your Alchemy API Key.
  network: Network.ETH_MAINNET, // Replace with your network.

};

const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings);

// Print all NFTs returned in the response:
alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwner("0xshah.eth").then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alchemy.nft
        .getNftsForOwner("0x9E29A34dFd3Cb99798E8D88515FEe01f2e4cD5a8", {
            contractAddresses: ["0x0c2e57efddba8c768147d1fdf9176a0a6ebd5d83"],
        })
        .then(console.log)
```

not supported by sepolia yet!